# How to change input field for google autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

How can I change input field for `autocomplete` (Google Maps API)?

```
autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(inputField, options);

function func1() {
 // switch element inputField to inputField2 (how?)
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you want to achieve? Any Clarification regarding change input field. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have several input fields. When any of input fields are in focus, Autocomplete for search of places must work for a chosen field. Don't want to create autocomplete for each field.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places">
</script>
<input type="text" id="loc1">
<input type="text" id="loc2">
<input type="text" id="loc3">
<script
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function initialize(){
var autocomplete1 = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete($("#loc1")[0], {});
var autocomplete2 = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete($("#loc2")[0], {});
var autocomplete3 = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete($("#loc3")[0], {});

google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete1, 'place_changed', function () {
var place = autocomplete1.getPlace();
console.log(place.address_components);
});
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

I think this would be helpful : [autofill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31469778/google-autofill-api-for-multiple-text-box). Create a autocomplete variable each with inputbox and create a single listener or multiple listener.

I hope this helps